# How to speed up a python function with numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to speed up my implementation of [Floyd-Steinberg's dithering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) with numba. After going through the beginner's guide, I added the `@jit` decorator to my code:

```
def findClosestColour(pixel):
    colors = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [253, 134, 18]])
    distances = np.sum(np.abs(pixel[:, np.newaxis].T - colors), axis=1)
    shortest = np.argmin(distances)
    closest_color = colors[shortest]
    return closest_color

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def floydDither(img_array):
    height, width, _ = img_array.shape
    for y in range(0, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            old_pixel = img_array[y, x, :]
            new_pixel = findClosestColour(old_pixel)
            img_array[y, x, :] = new_pixel
            quant_error = new_pixel - old_pixel
            img_array[y, x+1, :] =  img_array[y, x+1, :] + quant_error * 7/16
            img_array[y+1, x-1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x-1, :] + quant_error * 3/16
            img_array[y+1, x, :] =  img_array[y+1, x, :] + quant_error * 5/16
            img_array[y+1, x+1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x+1, :] + quant_error * 1/16
    return img_array
```

However, I get thrown the following error:

```
Untyped global name 'findClosestColour': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

I think I understand that numba doesn't know the type of `findClosestColour` but I just got started with numba and don't know how to handle the error.

Here's the code I used to test the function:

```
image = cv2.imread('logo.jpeg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_out = floydDither(img)
```

And Here's the test image I used.
[image]

Comment: Did you try applying the `@jit` decorator to `findClosestColour` as well?

Comment: Did you try applying the @jit decorator with the nopython argument set to False?

Comment: @folgerit I applied the `@jit` decorator to `findClosestColour` and I get this error: ```numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)```

Comment: @yannziselman I tried setting the `@jit` decorator argument to false and I get some deprecation warnings. The overall performance didn't improve when compared to using plain python.

Comment: please provide a small runnable `img_array` for further investigations.

Comment: @Ali_Sh The original post has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, **it is not possible to call pure-Python functions from Numba nopython jitted functions** (aka njit functions). This is because Numba needs to track types at compile time to generate an efficient binary.

Moreover, Numba cannot compile the expression `pixel[:, np.newaxis].T` because of `np.newaxis` which appear not to be supported yet (probably because `np.newaxis` is `None`). You can **use `pixel.reshape(3, -1).T` instead**.

Note that you should be careful about the types because doing `a - b` when both variables are of type `np.uint8` results in a possible *overflow* (eg. `0 - 1 == 255`, or even more surprizing: `0 - 256 = 65280` when `b` is a literal integer and `a` of type `np.uint8`). Note that the array is computed in-place and that pixels are written before

---

The generated code will not be very efficient although Numba make a good job. You can iterate over the colors yourself using a loop to find the minimum index. This is a bit better because it does not generate *many small temporary arrays*. You can also specify the types so that Numba will compile the function ahead of time. That being said. This also make the code lower-level and so more verbose/harder-to-maintain.

Here is an **optimized implementation**:

```py
@nb.njit('int32[::1](uint8[::1])')
def nb_findClosestColour(pixel):
    colors = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0], [0, 128, 0], [253, 134, 18]], dtype=np.int32)
    r,g,b = pixel.astype(np.int32)
    r2,g2,b2 = colors[0]
    minDistance = np.abs(r-r2) + np.abs(g-g2) + np.abs(b-b2)
    shortest = 0
    for i in range(1, colors.shape[0]):
        r2,g2,b2 = colors[i]
        distance = np.abs(r-r2) + np.abs(g-g2) + np.abs(b-b2)
        if distance < minDistance:
            minDistance = distance
            shortest = i
    return colors[shortest]

@nb.njit('uint8[:,:,::1](uint8[:,:,::1])')
def nb_floydDither(img_array):
    assert(img_array.shape[2] == 3)
    height, width, _ = img_array.shape
    for y in range(0, height-1):
        for x in range(1, width-1):
            old_pixel = img_array[y, x, :]
            new_pixel = nb_findClosestColour(old_pixel)
            img_array[y, x, :] = new_pixel
            quant_error = new_pixel - old_pixel
            img_array[y, x+1, :] =  img_array[y, x+1, :] + quant_error * 7/16
            img_array[y+1, x-1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x-1, :] + quant_error * 3/16
            img_array[y+1, x, :] =  img_array[y+1, x, :] + quant_error * 5/16
            img_array[y+1, x+1, :] =  img_array[y+1, x+1, :] + quant_error * 1/16
    return img_array
```

The naive version is 14 times faster while the last one is **19 times faster**.

Comment: Nice work, sir.  Chapeau!